# Debug a node app that is started as npm start from vscode

Tags: node.js, shell, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a node app that is started  with npm start. The package.json has scripts.start pointing to a shell script which uses node executable to run the contents of the shell script which now bootstrap the whole application.

Comment: Why don't you just create a run configuration to debug the Node script that is executed from the shell script?

Comment: Please i will appreciate if am given a link to an example  where it was donre

Comment: Googling for "debug Node vscode" will already lead you to the [official documentation(https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging). Don't be lazy.

Comment: thanks i was successful. but the shell script requires a sudo